# How to prove one-to-one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove $(-1, 1)$ is equinumerous to $\mathbb{R}$ by finding a bijection function from $(-1, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
I've found a function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2-1}$, and it's a bijection obviously from its graph, but I don't know how to prove it is bijection rigorously. Any help, thanks!

Comment: You have to show $f$ is one-to-one and onto.  Do you know how to prove a function is one-to-one?  Do you know how to go about proving a functions is onto?

Comment: See also: [Show that the function $f(x)=x/(x^2-1)$ is bijective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3129901)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given function is continous and because of $$(\frac{x}{x^2-1})'=\frac{x^2-1-2x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{-1-x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}<0$$ strictly decreasing in the interval $(-1,1)$ Additionally, we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1+0} \frac{x}{x^2-1}=\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-0} \frac{x}{x^2-1}=-\infty$$

So the range is $\mathbb R$ , hence $f^{-1}(x)$ exists and is defined everywhere.

Comment: So we could prove a function is bijection by showing it has inverse rather than to prove step by step according to the definition of bijection? Such as proving injection is to show if   f(a) = f(b) then a = b?

Comment: Yes, but domain and range need not be the same. Here the bijection is between the interval $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb R$. If a function is continous , you can use the intermediate-value-theorem that guarantees that every value in the range is a possible value of the function.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple proof that $f$ is injective without calculus:
$$
f(x) = f(y)
\iff \frac{x}{x^2-1} = \frac{y}{y^2-1} 
\iff (xy+1)(x-y)=0
\iff xy=-1 \text{ or } x=y
$$
But $|x|<1$, $|y|<1$ implies $|xy|=|x| |y| <1$ and so $xy$ is never $-1$.

Comment: Thanks! I've never thought the question can be proved without continuous. Can surjection be proved in a similar way?

Comment: @Cathy, the answer by 高田航 does that.

Answer (score 3):

Injective: compute the derivative. The function is derivable in the whole domain. 
It is $\frac{x^2-1-x\cdot 2x}{(x^2-1)^2}= \frac{-1-x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}<0$ for all $x$ in the domain. So the function is in fact strictly monotone decreasing.

Surjective: Compute the limits at the endpoints of the interval.

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -1} \frac{x}{x^2-1}= \infty$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{x}{x^2-1}= -\infty$.

As the function is continuous, every real value is attained somewhere by the Bolzano theorem.

Answer (score 3):

To show that a function is a bijection you can simply show that there is an inverse function $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(-1,1)$ which can be found by setting 
\begin{align}
x & =\frac{y}{y^2-1}
\\ y&=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}  
\end{align}
We take the negative sign to stay within the domain, so we obtain $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x}$. 
Lastly, we can confirm that $f^{-1}\circ f(x)=x$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$ and similarly that $f\circ f^{-1}(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.